# Reverse for 'product_list' with arguments '('cars',)' not found

Tags: python, django

I get the following error when I try http://192.168.1.107:8000/shop/. 
However I do not get any errors when my shop_urls.py looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [


    path('shop/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),

    re_path(r'shop/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),

]
```

why can't I use a different name like `product_list_by_category`?

Also, `cars` is a category slug name and I do not understand why it is being called.

## Error

```
Reverse for 'product_list' with arguments '('cars',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop\\/$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.107:8000/shop/
Django Version:     2.1.4
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'product_list' with arguments '('cars',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop\\/$']

Exception Location:     /home/gravityns/PycharmProjects/prodgdscorehome/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 622
Python Executable:  /home/gravityns/PycharmProjects/prodgdscorehome/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.6.7
Python Path:    


main.urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include(('gdsauth.urls','gdsauth'), 'gdsauth')),

    path('', include(('gdsshop.urls','gdsshop'), 'gdsshop')),
]

shop_urls.py
  path('shop/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    re_path(r'shop/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_category'),
    re_path(r'shop/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),

View in question
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):

    context = {}

    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    context['title'] = 'Shop'
    context['category'] = category
    context['categories'] = categories
    context['products'] = products


    return render(request, 'gdsshop/products/list.html',context)


models


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='products') 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('gdsshop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('gdsshop:product_list', args=[self.slug])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your urlpatterns

```
path('shop/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),

re_path(r'shop/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
```

you have same name in two url path. Change name one of `name`

Comment: having this same name actually works. If I change the second url to anything else then I get the error mentioned above. This is what I can not understand.